# React js setState({}) modifies data in redux stores initial object directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

When I am setting the `this.props.setState()` which modifies the my redux stores initial_state object.

Following is my redux-store:

```
export const initial_state = {address:{firstName:"",lastName:""}}
export const store = createStore(reducers,Object.assign({},initial_state));
```

Inside my Component

```
class AddressForm extends React.Component{


constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state = {address:this.props.address};
this.onAddressChange = this.onAddressChange.bind(this);
}
  onAddressChange(e){
   let address = Object.assign({},this.state.address);
     address["firsName"].value = e.target.value;
     this.setState({address:address})
  }
  render(){
     console.log(this.props.address);
      return(...having input field with onChange=
                {this.onAddressChange}....)
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return({
     address:state.address
  });
}
export default connect()(AddressForm);
```

As per above code in console i am printing the `this.props.address` from redux store and this prints the value as `{firstName:"Typed in text box"}`

Actually i am modifiying only in state of the component by creating new address object and modifying only that state value.

Even I am not dispatching any redux event...

but still it modifies my intial_state in redux store why?

Thanks in advance guys.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Statement 1:**

`this.state = {address:this.props.address};` you storing the reference of store `address state`.

**Statement 2:**

```
let address = Object.assign({},this.state.address);
```

You are creating the clean copy and storing in the `address`.

But,

```
this.setState({address:address})
```

is not update the `address` variable from Statement 2 but instead updating the `address`  from Statement 1 which is reference for `address  state` from redux store.
That's why your redux store value is getting updated.

Comment: But in the `connect`, he hasn't specified `mapStateToProps`, although he has written it.

Comment: @AjayGaur I am talking about `this.props.address}` which initially undefined as he not passed `mapStateToProps` in `connect`

Comment: I didn't get that. I don't know how he is running the code. On `address["firsName"].value = e.target.value;`, it should give him error as `can't read value of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I reacted, but what first caught my eye is that `mapStateToProps`should be passed to `connect`'s initial call. I bet if you did a `console.log(this.props.address)` in the constructor, it would print `undefined`.

Also I wouldn't store a referance to props like this `this.state = {address:this.props.address};`. Rather use `this.state`for temp storage of the form values, and then pass this via an action to the store on form submit.

New to lending a helping hand here in Stack Overflow, so please let me know if I was unclear on anythig, or could be of further help :)